# Breeze: Specifying order of entity initialization

Tags: breeze

Through a breeze query we are fetching a set of entities.

The entity graph looks similar to this:

```
EntityA {id, prop1:EntityB}

EntityB {id, prop1:EntityC}

EntityC {id}
```

On the client-side, for each entity we have an **Initializer** method passed to *metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor*.

In the Initializer of EnitityA, we do this:

```
if (EntityA.EntityB.EntityC){
  //do things
}
```

We have noticed that, depending on the order in which properties are defined on the **server-side model**, EntityC is not yet initialized when this code is reached.

If on the server-side model, we defined the property of type EntityC **before** the property of type EntityB, then EntityC will be initialized when the above code is reached.

Is there a way to specifiy on the client-side which order entities should be initialized, without relying on the order they are defined server-side  ?

Comment: I'm running into this same problem...hoping for some answers. @Sam how are you able to define the order on the server-side even?